# Adding children to the Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas

I have a problem with adding childrens (lines) to the canvas, when I debug my code I see that canvas has childrens which I add, but I didn't see they on the canvas:
Here is my code:

xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="CanvasGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <Canvas Background="Bisque" x:Name="PatyczakCanvas"></Canvas>
</Grid>
```

c#

```
var _body = new Line
{
    X1 = 120,
    X2 = 120,
    Y1 = 20,
    Y2 = 75,
    Width = 20.0,
    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)),
    StrokeThickness = 20,
    Visibility = Visibility.Visible
};
_body.MouseLeftButtonDown += _BodyLeftMouseButtonEventHandler;
PatyczakCanvas.Children.Add(_body);
```

and example of manipulating the canvas:
Slider value changes method:

```
_body.X2 = _body.X1 + DlugoscSlider.Value * Math.Sin(KatSlider.Value * Math.PI / 180.0);
_body.Y2 = _body.Y1 + DlugoscSlider.Value * Math.Cos(KatSlider.Value * Math.PI / 180.0);
```

I also try to add lines to the grid instead of canvas, but when I manipulate the line, their width/height in which they are draw didn't changed..

If someone could help me I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change or remove the `Width` property:

```
var _body = new Line
{
    X1 = 120,
    X2 = 120,
    Y1 = 20,
    Y2 = 75,
    Stroke = Brushes.Red,
    StrokeThickness = 20,
};
```

The `Width` affects the visible area of the line.

You can see the effect if you use a higher value, e.g. `150`:

[image]

In your code, the `Width` is less than `X1` and `X2`, and the line is drawn beyond the visible area.

Comment: You are right with width attribute, but it's a little bit weird that with set this attribute, the whole line doen't show at the canvas. But thanks for help!

Comment: You're welcome! Indeed, it seems counter-intuitive, but `Width` is inherited from `FrameworkElement`, so it makes sense after all.